# Edit record before update in query subform Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

Here is what I have:

Two tables:

- `tblA`: `Index`, `Date_Time`, `User_Name`, `Event`, `Product_Serial_Number`
- `tblB`: `tblA_Index`, `Date_Time`, `User_Name`, `Event_Tag`

The field `Event_Tag` is used to classify different characteristics about the event like what you would see with YouTube videos, hence, the many to one relation.

I have a main form with the information of `tblA` displayed such as the `User_Name` and `index`. I have a subform with only the `Event_Tag` field displayed in a datasheet view whose control source is a query filtering by only the index taking from `tblA`.

I know in queries you can add records by typing in the blank record at the bottom (if it is enabled). I want to be able to type in a new `Event_Tag` record for the specific index in `tblA`. I am wondering it is possible to programmatically edit the record being inserted into the table before it is updated?

For example, I type in the blank record at the bottom of the subform `Defective Motor` and then use a vba code to take the `date_time` from the computer and the `index`/`User_Name` from the controls in the mainform and add it to complete the record, then insert it into `tblB`.

I hope this is a good enough example to show what I am trying to do.
I appreciate the feedback if anyone can direct me how to solve this, or if there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: why are you having username in both tables? tableA and B are linked anyway

Comment: Good question, I should have clarified more. I steal the name of the person who is using the form via environ(username) method. The person who created the record in tblA may not be the same person who creates a record in tblB. For simplicity I removed that from my initial description because I am more interested in the underlying method of completing a record before insert via a sub form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "onBeforeUpdate" event for the subform. within that event

```
txt_date.value = now()
txt_username.value = your string
```

and so on